# alias to member members doesn't compile

Tags: d

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

```
struct A
{
    int w;
    alias h = w; // works
}

struct B
{
    A a;
    alias w = a.w; // doesn't
}

void foo()
{
    A a;
    auto c = a.h;
    B b;
    b.w; // L18
}
```

dmd 2.065

```
aliastest.d(18): Error: struct aliastest.B 'w' is not a member
aliastest.d(18): Error: struct aliastest.B member w is not accessible
aliastest.d(18): Error: need 'this' for 'w' of type 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is trying to access a.w in static context (same as A.w), it does not use an instance of A struct, but A type instead. This will work:

```
struct A
{
    static int w;
    alias h = w; // works
}

struct B
{
    A a;
    // seems it is same as alias w = A.wl
    alias w = a.w; // does work too
}

void foo()
{
    B b;
    b.w = 8; // L18
}
```

Comment: Indeed a.w gets silently treated like A.w in this context.
So there's no other way than having boilerplate methods to forward.

Comment: So there's no other way than creating a boilerplate method to forward?!

Comment: it depends what you really want. You can use `alias a this;` in **`B`** struct but than everything from **`A`** would be accessible from **`B`**